# Как с помощью регулярки вытащить из строки нужную информацию

Tags: java, json, регулярные-выражения, парсер, jsoup

Пишу на Java. Получаю страницу стрима с ютуба (через JSoup) и вытаскиваю её код. Из этого кода нужно получить информацию о зрителях и лайках. Для достижения этой цели хочу использовать регулярку, но сколько я не пытался понять как их составлять, до сих пор не получается. Также хотел попробовать преобразовать это в json, но опять-таки ничего не получилось: получаю ошибку, что данная строка не является объектом json.

Помогите составить регулярное выражение или превратить строку в json чтобы удобно из неё вытаскиватт значения

p.s. сам код получаемый от ютуба https://pastebin.com/1biDfSnU

Comment: Рекомендую десериализировать `Json` в объекты и работать в коде с ними.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Проблема как раз в том, что у меня не получается превратить сроку в json объект для дальнейшей работы с ним. Возможно, я делаю что-то не так... Можете дать пример, пожалуйста?

Comment: Дарова. "Сейчас смотрят:(.[^<])*"  в конце условие вытаскивает все символы пока не дойдёт до первого открывшегося тега

Comment: А у тебя json там, ну тогда тоже самое Сейчас смотрят: "},{"text":(.[^}])* , в получившейся строке ищешь все цифры \d*

Comment: А че Jakson не работает?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался сам.
Вот код получения лайков и зрителей

```
private void test(String html) {
    JsonObject mainInfo = new JsonParser().parse(html).getAsJsonArray()
            .get(0).getAsJsonObject()
            .getAsJsonObject("contents")
            .getAsJsonObject("twoColumnWatchNextResults")
            .getAsJsonObject("results")
            .getAsJsonObject("results")
            .getAsJsonArray("contents")
            .get(0).getAsJsonObject()
            .getAsJsonObject("videoPrimaryInfoRenderer");

    JsonObject likesInfo = mainInfo.getAsJsonObject("videoActions")
            .getAsJsonObject("menuRenderer")
            .getAsJsonArray("topLevelButtons")
            .get(0).getAsJsonObject()
            .getAsJsonObject("toggleButtonRenderer")
            .getAsJsonObject("defaultText");

    int viewers = Integer.parseInt(mainInfo.getAsJsonObject("viewCount")
                .getAsJsonObject("videoViewCountRenderer")
                .getAsJsonObject("viewCount")
                .getAsJsonArray("runs")
                .get(1).getAsJsonObject()
                .get("text")
                .getAsString().replaceAll("[^0-9]", "")
    );

    int likes = Integer.parseInt(likesInfo
            .getAsJsonObject("accessibility")
            .getAsJsonObject("accessibilityData")
            .get("label").getAsString().replaceAll("[^0-9]", "")
    );

    String simpleLikes = likesInfo.get("simpleText").getAsString();
    
    System.out.println("Зрителей: " + viewers); //Зрителей: 7475
    System.out.println("Упрощенное кол-во лайков: " + simpleLikes); //Упрощенное кол-во лайков: 2,3 тыс.
    System.out.println("Полное кол-во лайков: " + likes); //Полное кол-во лайков: 2387
}
```